# Dispatchevent in tampermonkey JS script doesn't work at the third use

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I am writing scripts in the google chrome extension tampermonkey in javaScript to automatically fill in a form. One of the input fields, for the ID requires double enter for validation. The solution below is what I am using:

```
var input = $("#inputID");
input.val("value");
input[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13 }));
input[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13 }));
```

In the form there are two of these input fields at different sections in the form. The first of these works without any issue, however, the second input field has some error. The ID value is inputted however the validation does not allow the form to continue. My best guess is the issue lies with dispatchEvent. I have tried various solutions and have checked for any syntax errors yet I am out of ideas how to fix the issue.

Comment: 'the second input field has some error' - what's the error? Is the second element dynamically generated? Have you tried adding a short delay between each event to better mock keyboard input?

Comment: There is no errors in the console, the input field does not validate. I have a slight delay implemented, the ID value is inputted meaning only the validation through dispatchEvent  doesn't work.